# How do I toggle the height of a div

Tags: jquery, height

So I want a div (`#more`) to change its height from `105px` to `25px` once another div (`#clck`) was clicked. I kind of did it with:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#clck").click(function () {
$("#more").css("height", "325");
});
</script>
```

but after the first click, it doesn't go back to its initial height. I've tried `toggleClass` but it's not working.

Can anybody help me do this?

Comment: when do you want it to go back to initial height ????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle height of div using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689001/toggle-height-of-div-using-jquery)

Comment: @dku.rajkumar, after another click. I've checked the other post regarding this but I'm having problems with it.

Comment: check my answer... that may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the height in a new CSS-class and toggle this class using toggleClass.

Example:
HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
   height: 105px;
}

#myDiv.expanded {
   height: 325px
}
```

JS:

```
$("#myDiv").toggleClass("expanded");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Toggle height of div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689001/toggle-height-of-div-using-jquery). Could use .data() .removeData() with if/else, as this guy demonstrates simply

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EJmEs/)

```
$("#clck").click(function () {
    if($("#more").css("height")=="105px") // check for height
        $("#more").css("height", "325");
    else
        $("#more").css("height", "105");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to toogle the height in each click you can use a flag variable to remember the current height.

```
var flag = false;
$("#clck").click(function(){
    if(flag){
        $("#more").css("height", "325");
        flag = false;
    }
    else{
        $("#more").css("height", "105");
        flag = true;
    }
});
```